# Need help understanding syntax of android.volley.requestQueue documentation example

Tags: syntax, kotlin, synchronization, singleton, android-volley

I don't understand how the INSTANCE variable is getting assigned a value in this example taken from the [Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/requestqueue)

```
MySingleton constructor(context: Context) {
companion object {
    @Volatile
    private var INSTANCE: MySingleton? = null
    fun getInstance(context: Context) =
            INSTANCE ?: synchronized(this) {
                INSTANCE ?: MySingleton(context)
            }
}
```

I understand what the code is accomplishing; I just don't understand the syntax. It seems like there should be some equal signs in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually...

> It seems like there should be some equal signs in there instead of colons.

You're absolutely right! The example is wrong! It translates to following Java code:

```
private static volatile MySingleton INSTANCE;

public static MySingleton getInstance(Context context) {
    if(INSTANCE != null) { 
        return INSTANCE;
    } else {
        synchronized(this) {
            if(INSTANCE != null) {
                return INSTANCE;
            }
            return new MySingleton(context);
        }
    }
}
```

So as you can see, the INSTANCE variable is never actually set. -_-

It should be:

```
class MySingleton(context: Context) {
    companion object {
        @Volatile @JvmField private var INSTANCE: MySingleton? = null
        fun getInstance(context: Context) =
            INSTANCE ?: synchronized(this) {
                INSTANCE ?: MySingleton(context).also { INSTANCE = it }
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for clearing that up! I was beginning to question my sanity.